# Exporting Spring Cloud Sleuth spans automatically using Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry Exporter client library for Java

Tags: java, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, azure-monitoring, open-telemetry

I'm trying to use [Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry Exporter client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor-readme-pre?view=azure-java-stable) to export all traces/spans from Spring Cloud Sleuth to Azure Monitor. This integration seems to only work with the newest version of Spring Cloud Sleuth after the recent dependency version updates.

However instead of using `azureMonitorExporter.export(spanData)` manually, I would like to export all traces/spans automatically for the whole application by just adding a configuration for Azure exporter. This could then easily be added to a new project.

I don't have much experience using Spring/Sleuth/OpenTelemetry, but AzureMonitorExporter implements SpanExporter, so I thought one option could be to create a configuration class that contains the following.

```
@Bean
public SpanExporter exporter() {
    return new AzureMonitorExporterBuilder()
        .instrumentationKey("{KEY}")
        .buildExporter();
};
```

And then it could be used in the main class using:

```
@Autowired
SpanExporter exporter;
```

However I'm not sure if this is the right way or how to continue from here to actually get the exporter to start exporting traces/spans automatically to Azure monitor.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>trace-demo-5-updated</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>trace-demo-5-updated</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Sleuth with Brave tracer implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update (2020-01-26):

With today's [release](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/releases/tag/v1.0.0-M3) of Spring Cloud Sleuth OTel (`spring-cloud-sleuth-otel:1.0.0-M3`) and The OTel [upgrade](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18512) in the Azure SDK, your original issue should disappear.

## Original Answer

(TL;DR: last paragraph)

The [Sleuth 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide) can help you out a lot here. Sleuth supports two tracing systems Brave (default) and OpenTelemetry (incubator).

In order to use OpenTelemetry, you need to remove Brave (just exclude `spring-cloud-sleuth-brave`) and add OpenTelemetry (`spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure` with `spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies`). See the docs I linked.

After you do this, your `SpanExporter` should be used, here's a [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/jonatan-ivanov/7cd2ba8a9eb1945d96876ff49218ecc3) I created based on yours. Btw, adding a sample project (e.g.: in a GitHub repo) could help a lot for everyone who is trying to help so that they don't need to create one themselves.

Unfortunately, this still won't work, you will still face with this exception at startup:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opentelemetry.common.AttributeValue`

This is because [opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor:1.0.0-beta.1](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure/opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor/1.0.0-beta.1/jar) depends on OpenTelemetry `0.8.0` while the latest `spring-cloud-sleuth-otel` ([1.0.0-M2](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/1.0.0-M2/), we released it today) is using the latest OpenTelemetry (0.13.1). Also, OpenTelemetry introduced breaking changes between minor versions, e.g.: the `AttributeValue` class [was removed in OpenTelemetry 0.9.1](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#091---2020-10-07).

Sleuth supports OpenTelemetry since Sleuth 3.0.0-M5, The OpenTelemetry version was 0.10 back then so there is no Sleuth version available that would support an OpenTelemetry version as old as `opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor:1.0.0-beta.1` needs.

So the solution would be fixing your `pom.xml` and `opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor` supporting the latest OpenTelemetry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would just like clarify some parts before accepting the answer.

The pom.xml I was using didn't throw any errors, but it also didn't seem to work because it was actually trying to use Brave? And now there is nothing I can do until `opentelemetry-exporters-azuremonitor` supports the latest OpenTelemetry version?

Comment: 1. Yes, maven was able to resolve the dependencies (no error) and Sleuth used Brave by default. You need to remove Brave and add Otel.

2. You can open an issue for them and ask for an update, here's the [pom.xml](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/monitor/microsoft-opentelemetry-exporter-azuremonitor/pom.xml#L44-L53), I guess you can open an issue in this repo.

Comment: Accepted answer and created a feature request https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18512

Comment: @Storm MS upgraded OTel in the Azure SDK, I also upgraded and released Sleuth OTel 1.0.0-M3 (see the updated answer).